# how to remove an outside array from numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I wanted to remove an array outside numpy array of arrays

my current array looks like this:

```
 array([array([1,2,3],[3,4,5],[34,31,23])])
```

I want to remove the first array:

**array**([array([1,2,3],[3,4,5],[34,31,23])])

Comment: convert to list

Comment: if your content is in x try x[0]

Comment: That isn't exactly what your code produces.  The inner `array` is missing a `[]` layer.  Also it is awkward to recreate.  But you might try  `arr[0]`, since it looks like a 1 element object array containing an (3,3) array.

Comment: x[0] is not working

Comment: Show the `shape` and `dtype` of this array.  What's the source?

Comment: shape = (1108,) ; dtype = dtype('O'). Each element is a 768 length numpy array

Comment: I want it to be the shape of (1108,768)

Comment: currently it is of the form:  array([array([1.....768],.....,n])])  ; n = 1108

Answer (score 0):

numpy .toList() function should convert the first array into a list of arrays.

```
arrayModified = array.toList()
```

where array variable is the array you want to convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.delete()` [Read Here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-delete/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20NumPy%20function%20np,from%20the%20NumPy%20array%20ndarray%20.&text=Specify%20the%20axis%20(dimension)%20and,a%20slice%20or%20a%20list.)

Let  `arr = array([array([1,2,3],[3,4,5],[34,31,23])])`

If you want to delete first array

use `arr = np.delete(arr, 0, 0)`

first 0 for index and second 0 for axis number

Comment: Same result. It is also altering the order of the array elements.